# Related to Bugzilla tool

Tags: bugzilla

How to add description column in Available Columns so that we can add this field in excel report from Bugzilla tool.
I am not getting the fixed bugs data in Bugzilla after 7 days so that i am trying to get excel report for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "you can't add the description column"

However, there are other ways to get this info.

1. You can export the search results as XML.
2. You can use the [API](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/api/) to query for the data